# In c++ code, what do the following keywords mean? SIGSELECT, U32, U16, U8

Tags: c++, struct, typedef

I have a question about keyword usage in a c++ struct.

I have seen a struct defined like this:

```
typedef struct {
    SIGSELECT signo;
    U32 id;
    U32 re;
    U16 id1;
    U8 id2;
}First;
```

Please help me understand these keywords: SIGSELECT,U32,U16,U8

Comment: Looks like a c-type struct declaration. Where are SIGSELECT,U8,U16 and U32? Are they macros or typedef?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What they "mean" is a quite deep question, and also depends on the environment you are in.

Those are type names, but not standard C++ types so they're not universally known.

A guess would be that the `Uxx` types are "unsigned integers", of the specified bit widths. So `U32` would be a 32-bit unsigned integer, what is known as `uint32_t` in C99 but has not yet been standardized in C++.

`SIGSELECT` is a bit harder, but the member is named "`signo`" which implies that this is a signal number. If the code is for a POSIX-like environment, it's quite likely that `SIGSELECT` is simply an alias for the default integer type, `int`. See [this page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal) for instance.

Some header does either

```
#define SIGSELECT int
```

or

```
typedef int SIGSELECT;
```

in order to introduce this new name (and similiarly for the other types mentioned).

To figure out if these are preprocessor symbols or actual `typedef`:ed type aliases, run the code through the preprocessor and read its output. If the wording changes (i.e. `SIGSELECT` turns into `int` or some other type) they are preprocessor symbols, otherwise they are `typedef`:s.

Comment: Actually, `uint32_t` is only known in C99 standard, which was not incorporated into any C++ standard yet (despite latest C++ standard being C++03, 4 years newer than C99). It will be incorportated in C++0x.

Comment: @Jan correct, although many of us `#include <cstdint>` and are familiar with those types in C++ as well.

Comment: [An anonymous user comments](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/202983): 'SIGSELECT' is a data type in the OSE environment that is an operating system developed by ENEA Sweden. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_System_Embedded

Comment: @AJG85 `<cstdint>` was not formally added to C++ until 2 months after your comment

Answer (score 0):

as @AJG85 mentioned in a comment on this thread, you can port the datatypes by including the standard library CSTDINT

```
#include <cstdint>
```

[this excellent article by Alex Allain](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-nullptr-strongly-typed-enum-class.html) describes the library and these datatypes in more detail.

Comment: The types defined by `<cstdint>` look like `std::uint8_t`, `std::uint32_t`, etc.